# react-rails .jsx file not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I installed react-rails gem and ran `rails g react:install` and works on `coffee-script syntax` but when i create a file `message.js.jsx` it gives me an

```
 ExecJS::RuntimeError


<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

any thoughts why this is happening?

running rails 5 on windows

Comment: Add the gem execjs in gemfile and bundle the application, It may solve your problem.

Comment: please share the full stack trace and the source code of `message.js.jsx`

Comment: one thing i notice is that if i add react on `'rails', '4.2.5.1'` `.jsx` file it runs fine. im not sure why it doesnt compile on `rails 5`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure extension js.jsx is right?    It's been a while but I don't think that extension will be recognised.

Is .jsx not sufficient?

Comment: thanks for the input. after investigating i find out that when i install react-rails on `'rails', '4.2.5.1'` it compiles okay, but not on `rails 5`